# Doctrine 2 - how to load entire dataset into cache for undirected graph without recursion?

Tags: php, graph, doctrine-orm, doctrine, hierarchy

We have what I would think is not an unusual use case of having entity `Foo`, which can have an arbitrary amount of both parent and children `Foo`s. This is realized via a `FooRelations` entity which has a parent `Foo` and a child `Foo`. `Foo` has `manyToOne` relations named `childFoos` and `parentFoos` which are set to `EAGER`.

Because the graphs are complex, attempting to load a full `Foo` results in literally thousands of database queries/trips - load `Foo` (one query), load all of `Foo`s children (one query), for each child `Foo`, load all of its children (one query each) and so on, in both directions.

The graph is not all that complicated or big, around 5000 `Foo`s total. `Foo`s also are small, we are talking about a few KB of data in total for the entire table worth. We would love to just say 'load all `Foo`s, and then load the `FooRelations` and just fill all objects in. Instead, all `Foo`s have `AbstractLazyCollection` as `getChildren`/`getParent`, which despite the `EAGER` flag do not get populated until accessed.

Are we doing something wrong ? Is there a way to accomplish what we are trying to do here ? Loading the data itself works with something like `SELECT f, p, c FROM Foo::class LEFT JOIN f.parent p LEFT JOIN f.child c`, so querying the data is not the problem, just having it stick in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Since the depth of the hierarchy is not known in advance, you will invariably end up having some recurring logic. The very fact that you can achieve this with recursion means that you can achieve your results via a [stack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-stack.php), albeit, if you use recursion, then the stack you use is a section in memory that stacks up function calls, called [the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation). You can convert your algorithm to be iterative. So, instead of self-calling a function, you explicitly use a stack and do something like this:

```
//$stack is a properly initialized empty stack
//$tree is a properly built tree where your hierarchy is stored
$stackItems = getNodesByParentID(null);
foreach ($stackItems as $stackItem) $stack->push($stackItem);
while (!$stack->isEmpty()) {
    $stackNode = $stack->pop();
    //The following two lines appeal to find and add, methods that are
    //assumed to be implemented, but they are less relevance to the point
    //of the question, so I will assume you have no trouble implementing them
    $parentNode = find($tree, $stackNode->parentID);
    add($tree, $stackNode);
    $stackItems = getNodesByParentID($stackNode->parentID);
    foreach ($stackItems as $stackItem) $stack->push($stackItem);
}
```

Essentially you do something similar algorithmically to recursion, whereas you are using heap memory rather than stack memory and your algorithm is iterative.

Yet, you will need to think about additional problems, like cycles in your graph or damaged data. For the sake of simplicity, I ignored these problems for now, but they are definitely solvable.

Comment: I'm not sure this reply, while well written, addresses my problem, which is that the already existing algorithm, which I have no problem with, for some reason does not use the Doctrine cache, which results in many database calls, which I would think would not change at all with your proposed solution ?

Comment: @Torque apparently I misunderstood your question, but its very last sentence indeed says that the caching is the problem. Is this extension helpful? https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine-extensions/tree